# Key Value Pairs are not being Impressed in logback

Tags: java, logging, logstash, logback, slf4j

I'm using logstash and logback with slf4j to be able to print Structured Logging in the console. I wanted to use *KeyValuePairs* to store values with a key and a value, "key" = "value".
I'm passing the values simply by Using the function as the second argument of the Logger method

```java
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
   logger.info("Test", StructuredArguments.kv("Key", "Value"));
}
```

And in the logback.xml file I have the following configuration:

```xml
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%kvp{}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

This should be enough to have what I want printed, a date, followed by the keyValue events, the level, logger and the message. Howerver when the log output is printed, keyValue field always appear blank, no matter what I do.

I've used kvp{NONE}, kvp{SINGLE}, kvp{DOUBLE}, and all that. And it does not seem to work ever. One could say that I could use "mdc" instead, and it works with mdc, but I want to try with key value pairs too, because I want to have different information in both mdc and kvp. So with that said, what could be the problem? I've searched a lot online, and couldn't find no one with this problem, and the information about this looks pretty scarce.

Answer (score 2):

Key value pairs can be sent using log builder pattern like this:

```
log.atDebug()
    .addKeyValue("key1", "someValue1")
    .addKeyValue("keyA", "someValueA")
    .log("Message");
```

When using [TTLLLayout](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/layout/TTLLLayout.java) layout, it is printed like this:

```
16:42:12.541 [main] DEBUG sk.qpp.some.app -key1="someValue1" keyA="someValueA"- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

When you use Pattern Layout (configured in logback.xml for example), you need to use `%kvp` for key-value inclusion. See documentation of [kvp in pattern layout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#kvp).

PS: Have a look at `log.atDebug().setMessage("Something happended").addArgument(...).log()` and other approaches to write more readable logging code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `%kvp` in pattern. You only need to put StructuredArguments of a
param in code, like this:

```
    logger.info("Test:{}", StructuredArguments.kv("Key", "Value"));
```

It will log message like: *Test:Key=Value*

Comment: Why do you think `kvp` can't be used in pattern? [Documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#kvp) seems to support it.

Comment: This is not key, value attached to log. This is only "string" passed as argument. I can do the same using: `log.info("Test:{}", "Key=Value")`. This is not an answer to the question